# About php memory_limit

Tags: php

My system memory is 128M and set memory_limit to 128M, can use php fread to download files over 150M size?
    I tried not! 
    Can be downloaded only 110M around!

thanks all,

```
    $sent = 0;
    $blocksize=(2 << 20);

    $fp = fopen($download_path, "rb");
    while($sent < $size){
        echo fread($fp, $blocksize);
        $sent += $blocksize;
    }
    exit(0);
```

I use this way, so how should I do?

Comment: Depends on *how* you download those files. If you read them into memory, well, yes, there's a limit. If you stream them right to disk, there are no limits.

Comment: fread let you  read  chunks of a file if i remember well , your problem might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don't try to read them all into memory in entirety. You should read your files in chunks and handle those chunks one at a time, if your requirements allow you to. This is just generally a good idea, no matter what you're doing and no matter how much RAM you have.

Comment: So how should read files in chunks and handle those chunks one at a time? thanks!

Comment: I do not have books, do not quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Ah! Well, let's fix that right away. Please purchase a good PHP book from which to learn.